# Eloquent: nested relation returns null

Tags: join, nested, eloquent

**Problem**
I want to get information about a campagin, and all characters part of it. But I also want the characters portraits. When I try to do that, I get the info and characters, but not portraits.

**Campaign model**

```
public function player_characters()
{
        return $this->hasMany('Sagohamnen\Character\Character', 'campaign_id')->select('id','campaign_id', 'name', 'portrait_id')->where('characters.type', 1)->where('characters.status', 1);
}
```

**Character model**

```
public function thumb_portrait()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Sagohamnen\Portrait\Portrait')->select('thumbnail', 'id');
}
```

**The Eloquent query**

```
return Campaign::select('id', 'genre', 'name', 'description',
'max_nr_players', 'rating', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->where('id',
$campaign_id)->with('player_characters.thumb_portrait')->first();
```

**The result**

```
string(139) "select `id`, `genre`, `name`, `description`, `max_nr_players`, `rating`, `created_at`, `updated_at` from `campaigns` where `id` = ? limit 1"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
string(165) "select `id`, `campaign_id`, `name`, `portrait_id` from `characters` where `characters`.`type` = ? and `characters`.`status` = ? and `characters`.`campaign_id` in (?)"
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
}
string(71) "select `thumbnail`, `id` from `portraits` where `portraits`.`id` in (?)"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
}
```

**Character DB-table**

```
id - name - portrait_id
1    Gandalf  3
```

**Portrait DB-table**

```
id - thumbnail
3  -  http://wwww....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I change the relation method "thumb_portrait" to "portrait", the portrait data shows up. Apparently the relation method should have the same name as the foreign key (unless I pass a custom foreign key as a second argument).

According to the documentation about oneToMany inverse:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name
>   of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.